# mutt installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, mutt

I tried to install `mutt` on ubuntu 14.04 as follows,

```
sudo apt-get install mutt
```

and i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mutt : Depends: libtokyocabinet9 (>= 1.4.47) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mutt
```

but issue is not solved.

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-get install  libtokyocabinet9` and give me a comment with @A.B.

Comment: @A.B. Installed `libtokyocabinet9` and tried `sudo apt-get install mutt` but the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let `aptitude` solve the problem for you.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Start aptitude

```
sudo aptitude
```

In the bottom line problem solutions are offered.

[image]

Use <kbd>E</kbd> für Examine and <kbd>.</kbd> and/or <kbd>,</kbd>

Apply with <kbd>!</kbd>

And Go with <kbd>G</kbd>

---

An other great tool to fix broken packages is synaptic:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Start from dash with

```
synaptic
```

Or in a terminal with

```
synaptic-pkexec
```

Now you can fix broken packages.

Comment: Whie installing aptitude i got 
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude:i386 : Depends: aptitude-common:i386 (= 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxapian22:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: apt-xapian-index:i386 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Can you ever install anything?

Comment: I can install other applications i removed synaptic and again installed successfully.

Comment: Why you have removed the accepted answer?

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)